# How to upload images from my directory into my wordpress?

Tags: images, uploads, remote

I'm doing a paste the link onto `input` and then uses PHP(imagecrop) to crop and store the image onto server directory.

```
$imagesrc = $_GET['img'];
$img = file_get_contents($imagesrc);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($img);

$width = imagesx($im);

$height = imagesy($im);

$newwidth = '400';

$newheight = '800';

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

$filename = basename($imagesrc);
imagejpeg($thumb,'image/'.$filename); //save image as jpg
imagedestroy($thumb); 
imagedestroy($im);
```

My question is how to upload images that is stored in the directory into wordpress? I know how to do it using `<form>` using manually but no idea how to do it after successfully cropping the image then upload to wordpress database automatically.

**Update:**

Tried uploading or saving it to **wp-content\uploads** and then I looked up in to wp-admin/upload.php and the images that I uploaded is not showing there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for you. It has describe everything step by step and there are part 1 & 3 of that tutorial series. Follow them as well.
[Creating a WordPress Plugin Part 2: Uploading Media and using Web Services](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/07/creating-wordpress-plugin-part-2-uploading-media-linking-web-service/)